# How can I assign the driver to UNO DiscardPile.java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm creating an UNO project and am a bit confused about how to assign the drivers to my DiscardPile class.

Thank you in advance for any answers you may give.

Sincerely,
Jayda M

I've asked my fellow students for assistance and have scoured the internet for anything that could be helpful with no luck. My professor isn't helpful at all haha

This is the full code for the Driver.java file. If you need me to give you any of the others I have no problem doing so.

```
package unoGame;
import java.util.Random;
//import java.util.Collections;

public class Driver {
    public static unoDeck theDeck = new unoDeck();
    public static PlayerHand[] thePlayers;
    public static DiscardPile dp = new DiscardPile();
    public static int nextPlayer;
    public static Random getRandom = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        thePlayers = new PlayerHand[3];
        thePlayers[0] = new PlayerHand("name 1");
        thePlayers[1] = new PlayerHand("name 2");
        thePlayers[2] = new PlayerHand("name 3");

        theDeck.shuffle();
        System.out.println("Here is the Deck:  " + theDeck);

        System.out.println(" Welcome to UNO! ");

        if (dp.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(" Discard is Empty ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" Not Empty ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < thePlayers.length; j++) {
                thePlayers[j].addCard(theDeck.deal());
            }
        }
        nextPlayer = 0;
        showPlayers();

        dp.addCard(theDeck.deal());

        while (checkForWin() == false) {
            findNextPlayer();

            if (theDeck.isEmpty()) {
                theDeck.replenish(dp.clear());
            }
            playerTurn();
        }
        System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer], getName() + " Wins!")
    }
        public static void showPlayers() {
            for (PlayerHand p : thePlayers)
                System.out.println(p);
        }
        public static boolean checkForWin() {
            if (p.isWin()) {
                win = true;
            }
            return win;
        }

    public static void findNextPlayer() {
        nextPlayer++;
        nextPlayer = nextPlayer % thePlayers.length;
        if(dp.getTopCard().getValue()=="SK") {
            nextPlayer++;
            nextPlayer = nextPlayer % thePlayers.length;
        }
        if(dp.getTopCard().getValue() == "D2") {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                thePlayers[nextPlayer].addCard(theDeck.deal());
            }
        }
        if(dp.getTopCard().getValue() == "W4") {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                thePlayers[nextPlayer].addCard(theDeck.deal());
            }
        }
        if(dp.getTopCard().getValue() == "RV") {
            for(int i = 0; i < thePlayers.length / 2; i++) {
                PlayerHand rev = thePlayers[i];
                thePlayers[i] = thePlayers[thePlayers.length - i -1];
                rev = thePlayers[thePlayers.length - i -1];
                if(nextPlayer == 0) {
                    nextPlayer = 0;
                }
                if(nextPlayer == 2) {
                    nextPlayer = 1;
                }
            }
            nextPlayer++;
        }
    }
    public static void playerTurn() {
        if (thePlayers[nextPlayer].hasMatch(dp.getTopCard())) {
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer].getName() + " has a match!");
            unoCard c = thePlayers[nextPlayer].playCard(dp.getTopCard());
            dp.addCard(c);
            if(c.getValue().equals("W")) {
                c.setColor(theDeck.newColor());
            }
            if(c.getValue().equals("W4")) {
                c.setColor(theDeck.newColor());
            }
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer].getName() + " played a: "  dp.getTopCard());
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer]);
        }
        else {
            unoCard c = theDeck.deal();
            thePlayers[nextPlayer]c.addCard(c);
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer].getName() + " drew a: " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

There are errors are on these lines of code: 46, 50, 57, 58, 60, 106 and 111. Most of them are saying they're undefined, and I'm unsure of where to do so amongst my files. I'm expecting the Driver to run the game as a whole, so because it's gone wack I can't run the build properly. If you need more information to work with, I'll gladly give it to you!

EDIT:
The lines and/or words where the errors are taking place have asterisks around them
[The error descriptions with their corresponding lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC6nk.png)

[The printed console error after running Driver. Hopefully this works for the Reproducible Example required :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeBUm.png)

Comment: I apologize for my incredible ignorance, but which line is line 46? Also please forgive me but my crystal ball is being fixed, so can you post details of the errors you claim to be getting?

Comment: Ah, my bad haha:    46 is theDeck.replenish(dp.clear());

Comment: I'm going to update my question with a picture of the errors for you...

Comment: [edit] your question and post _all_ the code of class `Driver`

Comment: Done deal mate. You want me to post the other corresponding files as well(DiscardPile, PlayerHand, etc)?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Since you are getting compilation problems with class `Driver` only, let's start with that class only.

Comment: Okay. I'll try shortening the code to focus in on the main lines of error. But sounds like a plan to only work with the Driver class. All the others have no errors.

Comment: Oops, silly me. Classes `unoDeck`, `PlayerHand` and `DiscardPile` are all referenced from class `Driver`. Without the referenced classes, class `Driver` does not compile.

Comment: Haha yeah. I'll put them in a google drive folder and share it, that might be easier in meeting stack's rules in terms of how much code to post. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yChc-Mff2QEXsWWUMj6PO2SbTwyIWKLG

Comment: You uploaded the compiled `.class` files and not the `.java` source code files.

Comment: Fixed it! They should be showing in the folder now.

Comment: Join me in [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201153/featherwaver-abra)

Comment: Sorry, it won't allow me to respond to your messages in the chat room, but yes I did from my professor's code while explaining how to carry out the rest of this project.

Comment: There really was no useful baseline information he gave us in what to do in order to work on the project so I've resulted to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your `Driver` class with compilation problems fixed. I suggest you compare it with your current code in order to see what I changed.

I also needed to add method `replenish()` in class `unoDeck` because it didn't exist and is called from class `Driver`. Right now that method does nothing. As I said, I only added it in order to fix the compilation error.

```java
package unoGame;

import java.util.Random;

public class Driver {
    public static unoDeck theDeck = new unoDeck();
    public static PlayerHand[] thePlayers;
    public static DiscardPile dp = new DiscardPile();
    public static int nextPlayer;
    public static Random getRandom = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thePlayers = new PlayerHand[3];
        thePlayers[0] = new PlayerHand("name 1");
        thePlayers[1] = new PlayerHand("name 2");
        thePlayers[2] = new PlayerHand("name 3");

        theDeck.shuffle();
        System.out.println("Here is the Deck:  " + theDeck);

        System.out.println(" Welcome to UNO! ");

        if (dp.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(" Discard is Empty ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" Not Empty ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < thePlayers.length; j++) {
                thePlayers[j].addCard(theDeck.deal());
            }
        }
        nextPlayer = 0;
        showPlayers();

        dp.addCard(theDeck.deal());

        while (checkForWin() == false) {
            findNextPlayer();

            if (theDeck.isEmpty()) {
                theDeck.replenish(dp.clear());
            }
            playerTurn();
        }
        System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer].getName() + " Wins!");
    }

    public static void showPlayers() {
        for (PlayerHand p : thePlayers)
            System.out.println(p);
    }

    public static boolean checkForWin() {
        boolean win = false;
        if (thePlayers[nextPlayer].isWin()) {
            win = true;
        }
        return win;
    }

    public static void findNextPlayer() {
        nextPlayer++;
        nextPlayer = nextPlayer % thePlayers.length;
        if (dp.getTopCard().getValue() == "SK") {
            nextPlayer++;
            nextPlayer = nextPlayer % thePlayers.length;
        }
        if (dp.getTopCard().getValue() == "D2") {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                thePlayers[nextPlayer].addCard(theDeck.deal());
            }
        }
        if (dp.getTopCard().getValue() == "W4") {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                thePlayers[nextPlayer].addCard(theDeck.deal());
            }
        }
        if (dp.getTopCard().getValue() == "RV") {
            for (int i = 0; i < thePlayers.length / 2; i++) {
                PlayerHand rev = thePlayers[i];
                thePlayers[i] = thePlayers[thePlayers.length - i - 1];
                rev = thePlayers[thePlayers.length - i - 1];
                if (nextPlayer == 0) {
                    nextPlayer = 0;
                }
                if (nextPlayer == 2) {
                    nextPlayer = 1;
                }
            }
            nextPlayer++;
        }
    }

    public static void playerTurn() {
        if (thePlayers[nextPlayer].hasMatch(dp.getTopCard())) {
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer].getName() + " has a match!");
            unoCard c = thePlayers[nextPlayer].playCard(dp.getTopCard());
            dp.addCard(c);
            if(c.getValue().equals("W")) {
                c.setColor(theDeck.newColor());
            }
            if(c.getValue().equals("W4")) {
                c.setColor(theDeck.newColor());
            }
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer].getName() + " played a: " + dp.getTopCard());
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer]);
        }
        else {
            unoCard c = theDeck.deal();
            thePlayers[nextPlayer].addCard(c);
            System.out.println(thePlayers[nextPlayer].getName() + " drew a: " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Sorry for the mishaps along the way in communication, it was my bad haha. Have a good rest of your day. And I'll keep you in mind for the tutoring :)